# Creating new domain in o365

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365

We have a domain in SharePoint online as say xyz.com on cloud. Now we have the requirement which cannot be fitted in existing domain. So we are thinking to have new domain as abc.com. I just want to know we have the space on cloud and also we have the domain already so here do we have to purchase DNS for abc.com or what is the process to create the new Domain without the DNS?

Comment: Do you want to add a new vanity domain to your tenant-public.sharepoint.com or you wan to create your teamsites under a new tenant Tenant2.sharepoint.com/sites/sitecollection?

Comment: I want to create a new site collection under a new tenant sharepoint.com/sites/sitecollection

Comment: sorry for the previous comment ... we want new domain ... here is the details ...  I want to create a entire new domain because site collection on existing domain will not work, right?,  as we want to do a total different address from existing domain. Thanks

Comment: Now you lost me :)  Pls check my answer and let me know what exactly you mean by the domain. If it's vanity, e.g. ILikeIt.Com you can add it for your public site, but remember that public site feature is going away next year.

Comment: I know I make confusion, sorry. We have a domain abc.sharepoint.com. With the new requirement we need the new domain as intranet-sharepoint.com. How can we do that? I hope I make the question clear now.

Comment: At best it will intranet.sharepoint or abc-intranet.sharepoint. There has to be a dot (.) before sharepoint. After you have gone through the procedure, could you please share the details? How it looked like? What were the requirements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the tenant name, either tenant.onmicrosoft.com or tenant.sharepoint.com is by design not possible. There is no button or script that will help you change tenant to tenant2.

What MIGHT be possible is to contact Microsoft via Service Request. They may change the name depending on the new name's availability and probably some other prerequisites, like business reason. The change will affect all site collections. There is no way to have tenant1.sharepoint.com/sites/sitecoll1 and tenant2.sharepoint.com/sites/anothersitecoll in one tenant.

If you need to keep the current tenant for developer reasons (e.g. as a test environment), I'd suggest to contact Billing people about creating a new tenant/subscription and (possibly) transferring licenses from one account to the other.

Comment: Thanks! I will take help from MS support to change the name.

Comment: There is no use in contacting MS as they cannot change the domain name at any cost Dont waste time